# Propper way of getting rid of FilterRules statements when passing options?

Tags: options, optional-arguments

When passing options from a function `f` to a function `g` in the body of `f` one can use the `FilterRules` command to make sure `g` only gets options of `g`. For example

```
f[ x__, opts:OptionsPattern[] ] :=
  g[ x, Sequence @@ FilterRules[ {opts}, Options[g] ] ]
```

I find this quite cumbersome to be honest since for functions that call multiple other functions I would have to put the whole `Sequence @@ ...` in there. One way to get around this is by implementing a function which adds filtered options like:

```
addOptions[ opts : OptionsPattern[] ][ head_ ][ args_] :=
  head[ args, Sequence @@ FilterRules[ {opts}, Options[head] ] ]
```

so that you can just write

```
f[ x__, opts:OptionsPattern[] ] := 
  addOptions[opts][g][x];
```

Typically, however, when I implement a solution like the one above, either

1. there exists a built-in function that does what I want to do but better, or
2. there's a good reason such a solution is not used (because it might fail for some cases or is unsafe for other reasons)

**Question** Does there exist a function like `addOptions` and if not: would the function above be safe to use for the purpose of filtering and passing on options?

Comment: You do not need the "Sequence@@" if you define  either a last argument like: options___ or if you specify options in a list.

Comment: `f[x__, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := g[x, ##] & @@ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[g]]`?

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to use `Sequence @@` when passing options to a function. This is because a `List` of options works just as well as a `Sequence` of options:

```
In[67]:= Options[g] = {"foo" -> 1, "bar" -> 2};
g[x__, OptionsPattern[]] := <|"x" -> {x}, "foo" -> OptionValue["foo"],
   "bar" -> OptionValue["bar"]|>

In[69]:= f[x__, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := g[x, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[g]]]

In[70]:= f[1, 2, "foo" -> 17, "somethingElse" -> 3]

Out[70]= <|"x" -> {1, 2}, "foo" -> 17, "bar" -> 2|>
```

The only way this **wouldn't** work is if `g` is not using `OptionsPattern` and `OptionValue` to implement optional arguments.